# Do you need to reinstall Windows 8 if you want to use a SSD Drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd

I've heard that if you clone Windows 8 over to an SSD from an HDD that you will not get the SSD drivers which help windows 8 take full advantage of using the SSD like TRIM ect...

Is it required to fully reinstall Windows 8?

Comment: Windows should automatically detect the new drive's features if you clone the drive. If you need to install new drivers then do this..

Comment: There is no such thing as "SSD drivers" where did you hear this exactly?

Comment: I read it on some articles online and pretty sure I saw it referenced on SU a few times too